# Merge two select sentences with different joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have these two selects, the differences are in the join table and the case inside the sum

```
select
table1.col1
sum(case when table1.col2 = 'C1' then table1.value else 0 end) as C1
from table1
join table2 on table1.col3 = table2.col3
group by table1.col1

select
table1.col1
sum(case when table1.col2 = 'C2' then table1.value else 0 end) as C2
from table1
join table3 on table1.col3 = table3.col3
group by table1.col1
```

How can I merge these querys into a single select? the problem is I want all the 'C1' rows only when is joined with table2, the same way with 'C2'.
This is an example of the joins, as you can see the col3 in both joins are equivalent (in terms of type of column) but not in value

```
select table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col3 from table1 join table2 on table1.col3 = table2.col3

table1.col1 |   table1.col2 |   table2.col3
'COD1'              'C1'        543
'COD1'              'C2'        329
'COD2'              'C2'        123
'COD1'              'C1'        943

select table1.col1, table1.col2, table3.col3 from table1 join table3 on table1.col3 = table3.col3

table1.col1 |   table1.col2 |   table3.col3
'COD2'              'C2'        632
'COD1'              'C1'        895
'COD1'              'C2'        248
'COD2'              'C1'        458
```

Comment: . . Your queries are syntactically incorrect.  They have the `sum()` function in the `select` but not `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right, edited

Answer (score 2):

If you want all C1 and C2 in single column then you can go for UNION or UNION ALL(duplicates are also included):

```
select
table1.col1
sum(case when table1.col2 = 'C1' then table1.value else 0 end) as C1
from table1
join table2 on table1.col3 = table2.col3
union
select
table1.col1
sum(case when table1.col2 = 'C2' then table1.value else 0 end) as C2
from table1
join table3 on table1.col3 = table3.col3
```

And if you want C1 and C2 in separate columns then you can simple add case statement for column C2 in your first query:

```
select
table1.col1
sum(case when table1.col2 = 'C1' then table1.value else 0 end) as C1,
sum(case when table1.col2 = 'C2' then table1.value else 0 end) as C2
from table1
join table2 on table1.col3 = table2.col3
join table3 on table1.col3 = table3.col3
```

Comment: For your second query, I want the 'C2' rows exclusively from table3

Comment: Then you can add one more join in the query. I've edited the second query for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand the question but what about

```
select col1, C1, C2
from table
left join ( ... first query ...) as t1 using(col1)
left join ( ... second query ...) as t2 using(col2)
```

Using this technique you probably can transform the subqueries into joins.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... where is the 'on' after each join?

Comment: I'm using 'using' instead of on that's (almost) equivalet ton on (left.col1 == rigt.col2). I made a typo is should using(col1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your queries should have the obvious `group by` clause, you can do:

```
select t1.col1,
       sum(case when t1.col3 in (select col3 from table2) and
                     t1.col2 = 'C1'
                then t1.value else 0
           end) as C1,
       sum(case when t1.col3 in (select col3 from table3) and
                     t1.col2 = 'C2'
                then t1.value else 0
           end) as C2
from table1 t1
group by t1.col1;
```

I would caution you from doing explicit joins.  Multiple matching rows in the `table2` and `table3` would throw off your sums.